# Better example of incorrect statement coverage meaning?

Tags: c#, code-coverage

I am trying to demonstrate that 100% statement coverage does not mean much in terms of proving and testing. I cannot think of any easy example, this is my best attempt:

```
TestObject t = null;

            if (Console.ReadLine() == "A")
            {
                t = new TestObject();
                t.Value = 5;

            }
            Console.WriteLine(t.Value);  //exception only when the IF statement was not run as the variable remains null.
```

Also when user presses "A", the statement coverage is 100%. However when anything else is pressed, the exception occurs.

Comment: Occurence of Exception is obvious as you are not allocating any instance to it.

Comment: Sure but isnt there easier way to show that 100% statement coverage is not enough? The instance IS created in the IF..that is the point of this example. It works when IF is true, crashes when IF is false.

Comment: @mihirj I disagree, I think this would be an easy bug to miss if you aren't paying much attention.  Although in default UI for Visual Studio it'd get a nice green underline warning you.

Comment: yes. hence it is a recommended practice to use a null check when u r not sure whether memory is going to be allocated to an object or not.

Comment: So, statement coverage isn't an adequate criterion for proof of perfect testing. Branch coverage is better; but you can find counterexamples where problems aren't revealed by that, either. So, other coverage criteria are proposed, e.g, MC/DC, "path coverage", etc. There are some 150 kinds of "coverage" defined in the literature, each of which helps in assuring that certain kinds of errors aren't missed. Since you can't get it perfect right, what you must do is to choose one of these and live with the warts. Branch coverage is commonly chosen cuz one can normally get tools; others not so much.

Comment: .. a simpler example of 100% coverage not proving anything is the program, "print 'Wrong Answer'".   If you execute this program by any method, you get 100% coverage.   It still prints the wrong answer.  Your tests have to actually be effective, and nothing about your coverage criteria will help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

I would say your example is the good for that purpose.

- You have complete (100%) statement coverage with just one test case. The bug was not revealed.
- From the coverage point of view, there are two branches (IF evaluates TRUE or FALSE) and only one is covered (50%). If branch coverage reaches 100%, the bug will be exposed. This is called branch coverage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are incorrect in your assertion.  With 100% statement coverage you can be sure that you are able to devise test cases to verify ALL your code.  You seem to be confusing the idea that because you are able to hit every line in your code using a unit test that it is being fully tested with one test case.

Comment: Actually it is correct - statement coverage simply means ALL statements are executed. This can happen here. But there is only 50% decision coverage whic is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Steve Cornnett, from Bullseye test coverage tool, has a fantastic article called "[What is wrong with Statement Coverage?](http://www.bullseye.com/statementCoverage.html)"

You will find a complete analisys on why statement coverage is consider as the weakest form of coverage.